# MySQL replication with ReplicationDriver : How does connection pool work?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, database-replication, apache-commons-dbcp

I am wondering how Connection objects maintain connections with master-slave hosts when ReplicationDriver is used with a connection pool library such as DBCP.

As for my understanding (please refer to the following image) , in the normal JDBC case , Connection object keep an TCP connection to the db-server.

In the case of ReplicationDriver , does one Connection object keep several TCP connections to each of the server. (master and slaves)?

[image]

Comment: You could look at the sourcecode of the MySQL driver if you want to know.

Comment: yes, this is how it works